# If $f(5 + x) = f(5 - x) \forall x \in \mathbb R$ and $f(x) = 0$ has four distinct real roots, then what's the sum of roots?

Tags: functions, roots

I have been able to find the 2 roots by the following way :-

```
Let a be one root of f(x). Then 
f(a) = 0
=>f(5-5+a) = 0
=>f[5-(5-a)] = 0
=>f[5+(5-a)] = 0
=>f(10-a) = 0 i.e. (10-a) and (a) are 2 roots of f(x).
```

How can I find the other 2 roots? Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can help if you think more geometrically about it. The condition that $\color{blue}{f(5+x)=f(5-x)}$ for all real $x$ tells you that the graph of the function is symmetric about the vertical line $x=5$. [Compare this with the definition of *even* functions: $f(x)=f(-x)$, or equivalently, $f(0+x)=f(0-x)$, whose graphs are symmetric about the $y$-axis, i.e. about the vertical line $x=0$.] This means that, unless $x=5$ is a root, all other roots come in pairs, lying symmetrically around $x=5$.

We're given that there are four roots, so $x=5$ indeed is not a root — otherwise, we would have an odd number of roots, since this one doesn't have a pair. Now, think about any one pair of roots: what is their sum? Since they are symmetric around $x=5$, they lie at the same distance from it, say, $r$ units away. So they are the numbers like $x_1=5+r$ and $x_2=5-r$, and their sum is …

Comment: thank you...this was very well explained....got to see the bigger picture..

Comment: @MdGhausAli: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing starting with $b$ as the third root and find $10-b$ for the fourth.  Then the problem asks for the sum of the roots.

Comment: even i was thinking of the same way...but what if the number of roots would have been odd number like 5 roots or 7 roots... then how can we find that one..middle positioned root? what should we assume in that case?

Comment: @MdGhausAli if it is odd set $10-a=a$ to get $a=5$ as one roots proceed similarly for the rest even number of roots